# How to properly override the default router?

Tags: symfony

So I've made a class that extends the `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router`
and defined as my default in the config using `router.class: My\Bundle\Router\Class`, but now each time I change something so simple as a route pattern or name, I get...

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /.../app/cache/dev/classes.php on line 312

In that line there is:

```php
$this->collection = $this->container->get('routing.loader')->load($this->resource, $this->options['resource_type']);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this->container` is private in the `Router` class. You can't access it directly.

You need to make it accessible explicity:

```php
/**
 * Router 
 */
class Router extends BaseRouter
{
    protected $container;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param ContainerInterface $container A ContainerInterface instance
     * @param mixed              $resource  The main resource to load
     * @param array              $options   An array of options
     * @param RequestContext     $context   The context
     * @param array              $defaults  The default values
     */
    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, $resource, array $options = array(), RequestContext $context = null, array $defaults = array())
    {
        $this->container = $container;

        parent::__construct($container, $resource, $options, $context, $defaults);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you guys! it was the problem, the "private"... it was driving me crazy and I didn't saw it.